# Discourse/Rhetorical structure in poetic writings

Tags: discourse-analysis, discourse, poetry

There are several taxonomies for describing relations between rhetorical/discourse components in prose text (PDTB, RST, etc).  Has anyone tried to describe the sort of relationships between elements of discourse that exist in poetic texts?

Comment: I'd be surprised; moreover, given the fashion in lyric poetry for allusion and implicature, the relations between discourse units in poetry would be deliberately underspecified—though where it can be inferred, I'd be surprised if it was essentially different from the relations in prose. "Elaboration" can go a long way...